# Wordpress : Remove "sub-menu" class in UL

Tags: wordpress, menu

I am trying to convert HTML to Wordpress and I am having troubles with menus.

The menu is a 3 level drop-down menu, I am outputting it with wp_nav_menu and this is how it formats.

```
    <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
         <li>Home</li>
         <li>Blog</li>
             <ul class="sub-menu">
                 <li>Level 2</li>
                     <ul class="sub-menu">
                         <li>Level 3</li>
                     </ul>
             </ul>
         <li>Portfolio</li>
         <li>Contacts</li>
    </ul>
```

Basically I want to remove the "sub-menu" class from the /s in the 2nd level and 3rd level.

This is how I want it to be:

```
     <ul id="nav" class="sf-menu">
         <li>Home</li>
         <li>Blog</li>
             <ul>
                 <li>Level 2</li>
                     <ul>
                         <li>Level 3</li>
                     </ul>
             </ul>
         <li>Portfolio</li>
         <li>Contacts</li>
    </ul>
```

Is this possible to do with a custom walker class?

Answer (score 1):

There is a wordpress 'setting' fkr that:

As you can see:[Function Reference/wp nav menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

you can remove the ul by writing this when you call the `wp_nav_menu`:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'items_wrap' => '%3$s' ) ); ?>
```

this should work. you also have some other Parameters for the nav menu: it's id, container_class and more.

Answer (score -1):

you can use below code :

```
$(function() {
    $('.sf-menu ul').removeClass('sub-menu');
});
```